# How to bind to a collection contained in an other project/namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml

i did this:

```
this.combobox.ItemsSource = Common.Component.ModuleManager.Instance.Modules;
```

to bind the combobox to a collection, which is located in an other project/namespace. But i had to move the `ComboBox` into a DataTemplate.

Now i need to do something like that:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Common.Component.ModuleManager.Instance.Modules}"/>
```

I don't want to list all of my tries, but none were successful.
Any better Ideas?

Comment: I just compiled and ran a program with your exact code - worked fine. The only thing I didn't do was put the class into a different assembly. There must be more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: Does the XamlParseException give you any details as to what specifically it's complaining about? Does it go away if you remove the ItemsSource attribute from the ComboBox?

Comment: Yes, if i remove the ItemsSource attribute there is no exception. And there is no specifically complain the stacktrace i could see.
But i uploaded it, maybe you find something i missed.
http://www.informatik.uni-rostock.de/~mb004/XamlParseException.txt
(Sorry about the german in there)

Comment: You've got me stumped, that's for sure. That error happens at runtime? It compiles ok?

Comment: yeah ... on load of the ComboBox. If the ContentenPresenter shows up an ArtifactViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map the .NET namespace to an XML namespace at the top of your XAML file:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WindowsApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:q="clr-namespace:Common.Component">
```

So now "q" is mapped to the "Common.Component" namespace. Now you can use the x:Static markup extension to access the static "Instance" property of your ModuleManager class:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Modules,Source={x:Static q:ModuleManager.Instance}}" />
```

See if that works for you.

**Edit**

One more thing: If your "Common.Component" namespace lives in a separate assembly, you need to tell the XAML that:

```
xmlns:q="clr-namespace:Common.Component;assembly=CommonAssemblyFilename"
```

Comment: This ends in a XamlParseException on load of the ComboBox

Comment: It did? That's ... weird. Never seen VS do that. Ok, can you update your question with more details on the "ModuleManager" class? Do I have it right that that's the class and Instance is a static property? 'Coz that XAML should work.

Comment: Out of interest, try "Binding Path=Modules" rather than just "Binding Modules" (keep the rest the same).

Answer (score 0):

On an unrelated note you might want to bind to an Observable collection instead for performance. More WPF optimization details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx).

> Binding IEnumerable to an ItemsControl forces WPF to create a wrapper IList<(Of <(T>)>) object, which means your performance is impacted by the unnecessary overhead of a second object.

Comment: I  don't need ObservableCollection. The Collection never changes after startup of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a workaround. There must be a Problem if the collection is contained in an other assembly.

I added a new class to the assembly of the XAML and the Binding.

```
public static class ResourceHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Common.Component.Module> Modules = Common.Component.ModuleManager.Instance.Modules;
}
```

Then i changed the binding to

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.,Source={x:Static e:ResourceHelper.Modules}}"/>
```

And this works fine.
Thx Matt for your help.

Comment: I still don't get it. I've used collections in other assemblies in just this way. Still, I'm glad you got it working!

Comment: I don't get it too. I altered some parts of the project and now i get that Excetion again, but not on every PC. It looks like that this problem comes from deep inside wpf.